# Flipping a coin and playing lotto

Tags: probability

In a recent discussion, the question came up, what the odds would be in a two staged probability experiment where first a coin is flipped and then one plays lotto. And wether winning the coin bet influences the chance of winning in lotto.

If I declare the experiment as "being the person that won the flipped coin and won in lotto", the two events are linked, right? Otherwise they are not.

Comment: How would the winning of the coin flip affect the lotto? And if you wait a year between the coin flip and the lotto, is the situation any different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to win both the coin flip and the lotto, you chances are the product of the chance of each one as they are independent.  So the probability is half the chance of winning the lotto.  Is there any more to the question?

Comment: No, that was exactly what I was wondering, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Probability doesn't have a memory.

Your chances winning in lotto don't depend on the result of the coin flip before.

Another typical example:
Imagine playing roulette, and the last 10 times the number was always red. Does this influence the next roll? Should you bet a big sum on black now? The answer is: No, the chance of getting black now is exactly the same as in every other situation.

Answer (score 0):

They are linked in the same way the experiments "person A wins a coin flip and in exactly thousand years from the coin flip a meteorite weighing 10 kg will hit Mars" are linked.